# Convert GMT date to IST

Tags: android, android-date

I am trying to convert GMT time to IST using the following piece of code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 Date date1 = sdf.parse("2015-01-25");
 sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
 Log.d("date",sdf.format(date1));
```

However, 2015-01-24 is being logged out in console.Where am i wrong?

Comment: What did you expect to be written?

Comment: 2015-01-26...today's date in IST

Comment: What's the system time zone?

Comment: It takes from cellular network.

Comment: i am in india . so it should be IST

Comment: what does it have anything to do with that? the server guy i'm working with is returning datetime in GMT format. i need to check the date in phone with the date returned by server.

Comment: in the above code, i'm just trying to convert the GMT time to corresponding IST time.

Comment: IIRC SimpleDateFormat uses your current Locale by default, so it's already parsing the Date in IST. Try calling sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); before creating the date object. Just note, though, IST is only 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of UTC, so parsing it into IST will still return 2015-01-25 if there is no time component attached

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on IST, you have to manually specify GMT. Like this,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));  // set this if your timezone is different

Date date1 = sdf.parse("2015-01-25"); // now time is Sun Jan 25 00:00:00 GMT 2015
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
Log.d("date",sdf.format(date1)); // now time is Sun Jan 25 05:30:00 IST 2015
```

Since IST = GMT + 05.30, you will get the same date.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet converts 2015-01-25 00:00:00 local time (whatever that is - seems to be east of IST) to IST and prints the date part of it.

So 2015-01-26 can never be output as IST would have to be at least 24 hours ahead of local time.